# Bridged NIC is unreachable via my host PC

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I have an ethernet connection between my AOSP device and host PC, once I set ipv4 for both on the same subnet i can connect between them but once I create a bridge on my AOSP device and make its NIC bridged i lose connection to my host.
PS: for bridge interface i gave it same IP as eth0 which become port once bridged
for Kernel config side i have the following macro
`CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER=m CONFIG_BRIDGE=y CONFIG_BRIDGE_IGMP_SNOOPING=y`
also i made all traffic allowed via iptable for that bridge interface but the problem persist and couldn't get the reason.

Thanks in advance !